# How to remove duplicate accounts in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I was wondering how to remove duplicate customers either from the table or exclude it in my query.  An Account_ID can only have 1 product associated with it.  And the account with the most recent purchase date is what should be showing.  An example is below:

```
    Account_ID, Account_Purchase, Purchase_Date
    1           Product 1         1/1/2016
    2           Product 1         1/2/2016
    3           Product 2         1/5/2016
    1           Product 3         3/12/2016
    4           Product 3         1/5/2016
```

Ideally I would only see:

```
    Account_ID, Account_Purchase, Purchase_Date
    2           Product 1         1/2/2016
    3           Product 2         1/5/2016
    1           Product 3         3/12/2016
    4           Product 3         1/5/2016
```

This should not show up because it is not the most recent purchase from account 1

```
    Account_ID, Account_Purchase, Purchase_Date
    1           Product 1         1/1/2016
```

Thank you all for help, folks!

Comment: Try grouping by account_id, sorting (descending) by date, and limiting to one record by group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply acquire the latest `purchase_date` using max and group by `account_id`. Then use inner join to get the other details from the acquired details.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME.* FROM TABLE_NAME 
INNER JOIN(
SELECT Account_ID, MAX(Purchase_Date) AS Purchase_Date 
GROUP BY Account_ID
) LatestPurchases
ON TABLE_NAME.Account_ID = LatestPurchases.Account_ID
AND TABLE_NAME.Purchase_Date = LatestPurchases.Purchase_Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query, please replace TABLENAME with your table

```
WITH CTE
AS (
  SELECT
  *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Account_ID ORDER BY Purchase_Date DESC) AS RN
FROM TABLENAME
   )
SELECT
  *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another query

```
SELECT
    t.Account_id,
    t.Account_Purchase,
    t.Purchase_Date
FROM
    tablename t
WHERE
    t.Purchase_Date = (SELECT MAX(Purchase_date) FROM Tablename WHERE Account_ID = t.Account_ID)
ORDER BY
    t.Purchase_Date DESC
```